# how do I sharpen grinder blade

Tags: grinding

I have a manual meat grinder that needs the cutting blade sharpened, how do I go about sharpening the blades so that it will cut the meat.

Comment: Have you looked for a professional that you can send it to?

Comment: I guess you don't have a belt grinder? If you do, it's usually easy. If you don't, it's tricky.

Comment: What sharpening equipment (eg aforementioned grinder, oilstones, waterstones, strops) do you already have? Except for using very cheap and suboptimal whetstones or sandpaper (and these are tricky, frustrating options), if no sharpening kit is present then acquiring it will cost more than a new/professionally resharpened blade or even a new grinder for most manual grinders. The most inexpensive whetstones that are "taken seriously" by people maintaining their own knives already cost $25+ .

Comment: Oh, and: Wisdom about sharpening shears/scissors might be more applicable here than such pertaining to knives - in the end, such a grinder is a shear. And whatever you do, do not attempt using dry machines (bench or belt grinder) without knowing exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Since there are a variety of grinder designs, it would greatly help if you posted a photo of yours.  Then we can advise more specifically.  IMHO, one can often usefully sharpen small cutting tools without breaking the bank on sharpening tackle.  Suggested reading:  https://www.amazon.com/Tauntons-Complete-Illustrated-Sharpening-Taunton/dp/1631860860/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1486214923&sr=8-1&keywords=Thomas+Lie+Nielsen  Although this book was written with woodworking in mind, it'll tell you how to sharpen practically anything!